# Is there a keyboard shortcut for Git Sync?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut for VSCode to synchronise changes to my remote repository right after a commit? I am working on MacOS if it can help.

I simply want to replace a click on the blue button in the following picture by a keyboard shortcut:
[image]

If not present by default, how can I add one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this command is called `git.sync` under the keyboard shortcuts (no keybinding is assigned by default).  You should be able to assign it a binding of your liking.

[image: git sync]

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know by chance if there is a way to find this information? (I mean, knowing that `git.sync`is the command behind the button).

Do I have to read the source code of VSCode itself?

Comment: @YannickVincent often you can search for what it is you are trying to do within the settings to find things like this.  All I did was search the word "sync" in the keyboard shortcuts and found it in the list. All I did was test out the shortcut (by assigning it some keybinding) and seeing if it performed a git sync in this case. Some of the shortcuts can be found in [this doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings), but it only really has basic ones.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it up so the `sync` is done automatically after a commit by going to this setting;

```
Git: Post Commit Command
```

and choose `sync` and then your commit button will look like this:

[image: commit and sync button]

assuming you have `Git: Show Action Button` enabled for the commit action.