# Change Source Control front Commit & Sync button

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, source-control-explorer

With a new VSCode update they changed the source control button from "commit" to "commit & sync". Personally I dislike this change and want to reverse it, so the main button will be "commit" again (I know that there are multiple options which you can select with the dropdown).

I already tried to add the following settings

```
     "git.showActionButton": {
        "publish": false,
        "sync": false
    }
```

which didn't work, but if I say

```
"git.showActionButton": {
        "commit": false,
    }
```

it just hides the button entirely.

Is there any possible way to change this?

#Edit 1
I found out that if I switch the project I also see the "commit" button as the main button, but if I switch back to the project of my company the "commit & sync" button appears again as the main button. Is there some kind of setting per project that can cause this?

#Edit 2
I checked a GitHub project and DevOps project. With GitHub I get the Commit button and with DevOps I get the Commit & Sync button. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Are you sure you use the latest VS Code? It is 1.74.2, and it still has button "Commit" available. Have you played with settings maybe, and messed up it a bit?

Comment: I am also running the 1.74.2 and the commit action is only available if I use the dropdown. I don't think that the settings had something to do with the problem, because my colleagues have the same button.

Comment: [Here is the setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73533446/184546) that makes the "commit and sync" button appear. My guess is that somehow that setting is being read-in from a file somewhere in your DevOps project. It could be intentional, or it could be that someone accidentally checked in the vscode settings that would normally be ignored. Try changing it and see if any files become modified.